# MVC3 C# + SQL Server : how to run sql query with multiple sum()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2008-r2, dbcontext

What I have:

- DB with data and connection to it by

  ```
  public class VMMExtDBContext : DbContext {...}
  ```
- inside this perfectly works something like this:

  ```
  public DbSet<VirtualMachine> VirtualMachines { get; set; }
  ```
- now I need a run query that perfectly run from MSSMS:

  ```
  select SUM(CPUCount), SUM(RAMSizeGB), SUM(PrimaryHDDVolumeGB) 
  from TempVMs 
  where VMCloudID='f51b73b5-fdb3-4af2-956b-b27fccc5e19d'
  ```

So I wrote code:

```
public QuotaPresenter(VMMExtDBContext db, Guid CloudID)
{
        string entitySQL = "select SUM(CPUCount), SUM(RAMSizeGB), SUM(PrimaryHDDVolumeGB) from TempVMs where VMCloudID='"+CloudID.ToString()+"'";
        //or = "select SUM(CPUCount), SUM(RAMSizeGB), SUM(PrimaryHDDVolumeGB) from dbo.TempVMs where VMCloudID='"+CloudID.ToString()+"'";


        var objectContext = (db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

        var query=objectContext.CreateQuery<UsedQuotaValue>(entitySQL);

        query.MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking;
        var QuoteValues=query.ToList(); //<--Exception here
        if (QuoteValues.Count > 0) {
            //На случай если нет ни одной виртуальной машины - оставляем по нулям
            UQV.CPU = QuoteValues[0].CPU;
            UQV.RAM = QuoteValues[0].RAM;
            UQV.PrimaryHDDGB = QuoteValues[0].PrimaryHDDGB;
        }
}
```

And when I run got an exception:

> *[System.Data.EntitySqlException] 
>   'TempVMs' could not be resolved in
>   the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables
>   are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces
>   are referenced correctly. Near simple identifier, line 1, column
>   68.*

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please tell us what version of SQL Server and Entity Framework, and which *approach* (database-first, code-first) in EF, you're using?

Comment: MSSQL 2010. C#4.0; database and data already exists and did not recreated

Comment: Sorry. Indeed. MSSQL 2008R2, MS .NET Framework 4.0.30319 SP1Rel and System.Data.Entity == v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are missing the schema indentifier from the table name. And the query will not work without a group by statement if i am correct.

Comment: I has manual assign table names here:         protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<VirtualMachine>().ToTable("TempVMs");
        }

Comment: In the database you sholuld se something like this: dbo.TempVMs. the 'dbo' could be something else

Comment: I tried to change query string and append dbo. to database name - it did not helped

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to use regular transact-sql in place of entity sql, and they actually are not the same. Take a look at [Aggregate Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399163%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), this *may* help you (I cannot test it myself)

```
SELECT VALUE SqlServer.SUM(p.ListPrice) 
FROM AdventureWorksEntities.Products as p
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I temporary solve this problem by moving SQL query to stored procedure :( That is acceptable for me now, so I can't loose my time anymore.